# Approximation in L1 function of uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I'm studying Billingsley's convergence of probability measures,

> If $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable($S$ is metric and $\mathcal{S}$ is $\sigma$-Borel) and $P|f| < \infty$ ($P$ is probability measure on $(S, \mathcal{S})$). then for each $\epsilon>0$, there is a bounded, uniformly continuous $g$ such that $P|f-g|<\epsilon$

I think this was related to Stone-Weierstrass theorem, but it does not correspond to that condition because this is not compact space. How to deal with this? I think if this metric is $\mathbb{R}^n$ then we can treat this as mollification(in Rudin's RCA), but in metric, how can I access to this question?

Comment: Where exactly do you find this statement in the book? (BTW Billingsley does not us these notations in the book. He writes $\int f dP$ for what you call as $Pf$).

Comment: @kaviRamaMurthy In chapter 2, problem 7. And he frequently writes it as $Pf$ (he mentioned at chapter 1 second paragraph, and actually in most case he use notation $Pf$. I think we are talking about different book..

Comment: I have a copy of Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures. The problems are numbered sectionwise and there is no such thing as Chapter 2 Problem 7.

Comment: I don't think your statement is true without further hypothesis.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy section 2 problem 2.9 is the one. Sorry for making you confused.